# How to ignore robots.txt errors to show in logs?

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

I am working on a crawler and want to do a polite crawl by obeying robots.txt. As it is a broad crawl, the log file becomes bigger in size and harder to process and most of the logging are because of robots.txt not found in most of the sites. 
So my question is. Is there a way, i can ignore robots.txt related error and not to log them as I don't need to know if we found it or not.

I already have errback handler to handle failed request for my crawler but it doesn't applicable to robots.txt as this request is made by scrapy middleware
Below is my code:
Spider:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'mobile'

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
         'https://site1.com',
         'http://site2.com'

     ]
     for url in urls:
         safe_no = 'test'
         yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                              errback=self.handle_error, meta={'safe_no': safe_no})
def parse(self, response):

    safe_no = response.meta['safe_no']
    html_doc = response.body
    text_data, contacts, keep_no = self.get_contact(html_doc, response.url)
    # print(contacts,keep_no)
    link_found = False
    data = []
    parsed_uri = urlparse(response.url)
    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)

    ###Parse data and get contact....

        if contacts:
            yield{
                'safe_no': safe_no,
                'url': response.url,
                'contacts': contacts,
                # 'text_data': text_data
                }



 def handle_error(self, failure):

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError : "%s"', response.url)

         elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError : "%s"', request.url)


        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError : "%s"', request.url)


        else:
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('Can not connect : "%s" ', request.url)
```

Below is the log of the crawler:

```
    2019-01-10 15:33:36 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.site1.com/robots.txt>: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: www.site1.com.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 975, in startConnectionAttempts
    "no results for hostname lookup: {}".format(self._hostStr)
```

As You can see in log, **handle_error** method doesn't apply to /robot.txt URL request. 
I did some research and found that we can configure middleware to ignore some of the errors, but so far no luck.

Comment: I've added the code for reference. Please see if it can help.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, though it seems to have indentation errors; could you please [edit] it into shape? On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K.

Comment: If you really only want to avoid logging, just skip logging if `request.url.endswith('/robots.txt')`

Comment: The log message doesn't tell us that the log handler is not being applied; quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small refactoring of your `handle_error`.

```
def handle_error(self, failure):
    # this is the original request
    request = failure.request
    if failure.check(DNSLookupError):
        self.logger.error('DNSLookupError : "%s"', request.url)
    elif request.url.endswith('/robots.txt'):
        pass
    elif failure.check(HttpError):
        # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
        # you can get the non-200 response
        response = failure.value.response
        self.logger.error('HttpError : "%s"', response.url)

    elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
        self.logger.error('TimeoutError : "%s"', request.url)

    else:
        request = failure.request
        self.logger.error('Can not connect : "%s" ', request.url)
```

Your log example shows a DNS lookup error, which IMHO *should* be logged regardless of what the specific URL is (it would fail even if it wasn't for `robots.txt`, and probably means the entire domain should be skipped there and then).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is reading this, a little hack together solution I did was to take the base class and comment out the extra detail being printed:

```py
class MycrawlerRobotsTxtMiddleware:
    DOWNLOAD_PRIORITY = 1000

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        if not crawler.settings.getbool("CUSTOM_ROBOTSTXT_OBEY"):
            raise NotConfigured
        self._default_useragent = crawler.settings.get("USER_AGENT", "Scrapy")
        self._robotstxt_useragent = crawler.settings.get("ROBOTSTXT_USER_AGENT", None)
        self.crawler = crawler
        self._parsers = {}
        self._parserimpl = load_object(crawler.settings.get("ROBOTSTXT_PARSER"))

        # check if parser dependencies are met, this should throw an error otherwise.
        self._parserimpl.from_crawler(self.crawler, b"")

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if request.meta.get("dont_obey_robotstxt"):
            return
        d = maybeDeferred(self.robot_parser, request, spider)
        d.addCallback(self.process_request_2, request, spider)
        return d

    def process_request_2(self, rp, request, spider):
        if rp is None:
            return

        useragent = self._robotstxt_useragent
        if not useragent:
            useragent = request.headers.get(b"User-Agent", self._default_useragent)
        if not rp.allowed(request.url, useragent):
            logger.debug(
                "Forbidden by robots.txt: %(request)s",
                {"request": request},
                extra={"spider": spider},
            )
            self.crawler.stats.inc_value("robotstxt/forbidden")
            raise IgnoreRequest("Forbidden by robots.txt")

    def robot_parser(self, request, spider):
        url = urlparse_cached(request)
        netloc = url.netloc

        if netloc not in self._parsers:
            self._parsers[netloc] = Deferred()
            robotsurl = f"{url.scheme}://{url.netloc}/robots.txt"
            robotsreq = Request(
                robotsurl,
                priority=self.DOWNLOAD_PRIORITY,
                meta={"dont_obey_robotstxt": True},
            )
            dfd = self.crawler.engine.download(robotsreq, spider)
            dfd.addCallback(self._parse_robots, netloc, spider)
            dfd.addErrback(self._logerror, robotsreq, spider)
            dfd.addErrback(self._robots_error, netloc)
            self.crawler.stats.inc_value("robotstxt/request_count")

        if isinstance(self._parsers[netloc], Deferred):
            d = Deferred()

            def cb(result):
                d.callback(result)
                return result

            self._parsers[netloc].addCallback(cb)
            return d
        else:
            return self._parsers[netloc]

    def _logerror(self, failure, request, spider):
        # if failure.type is not IgnoreRequest:
        #     logger.error(
        #         "Error downloading %(request)s: %(f_exception)s",
        #         {"request": request, "f_exception": failure.value},
        #         exc_info=failure_to_exc_info(failure),
        #         extra={"spider": spider},
        #     )
        if failure.type is not IgnoreRequest:
            logger.error(f"Error downloading robots.txt: {request}")
        return failure

    def _parse_robots(self, response, netloc, spider):
        self.crawler.stats.inc_value("robotstxt/response_count")
        self.crawler.stats.inc_value(
            f"robotstxt/response_status_count/{response.status}"
        )
        rp = self._parserimpl.from_crawler(self.crawler, response.body)
        rp_dfd = self._parsers[netloc]
        self._parsers[netloc] = rp
        rp_dfd.callback(rp)

    def _robots_error(self, failure, netloc):
        if failure.type is not IgnoreRequest:
            key = f"robotstxt/exception_count/{failure.type}"
            self.crawler.stats.inc_value(key)
        rp_dfd = self._parsers[netloc]
        self._parsers[netloc] = None
        rp_dfd.callback(None)
```

Then I added this into `settings.py`:

```py
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Custom one written so it doesn't log every 404 response
CUSTOM_ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    ...
    "mycrawler.middlewares.MycrawlerRobotsTxtMiddleware": 100,
}
```